# What is the best option to visualize the trending of a noisy graph, calculating a binned average or fitting?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a graph that looks like this
[image]

In python, what is the best option to visualize the trending of it, calculating a binned average or performing a fitting? I first thought in calculating the binned average and plot the mean (center) of each bin.
But I'm starting to think that I can avoid this and the task that comes with this approach (determining the size of the bins for example) by simply fitting it. And then comes the problem of the fitting, which polynomial order should I use for example.

It seems to me that both approaches have their pros and cons. My priority is to get a quick result.
Any thoughts?

Comment: You can apply some kind of smoothing, for example moving average or exponential smoothing. The term "best option" indicates that this is an open-ended question, which is not suitable for stackoverflow, you can ask this question in cross validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can consider doing a binscatter: http://esantorella.com/2017/11/03/binscatter/ which was inspired by a Stata library, most of which is distilled in these slides: https://michaelstepner.com/binscatter/binscatter-StataConference2014.pdf. Though if your data aren't linear the fit line wont mean much, but the aggregate points will look better.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).
Here's how to make one easily in using numpy and matplotlib: [https://stanford.edu/~raejoon/blog/2017/05/16/python-recipes-for-cdfs.html](https://stanford.edu/%7Eraejoon/blog/2017/05/16/python-recipes-for-cdfs.html)